# Can I restore a Vista restore point using a PE disk?

Tags: windows-vista, bsod, restore

I have a PC that continues to BSOD on *FLTMGR.SYS*.  I had hoped to boot to safe mode to return to a previous restore point but the BSODs as well.  Before I fallback to a reinstall, is there a way I can use a PE disk like BartPE to boot and kickoff the return to a previous restore point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. I found the answer.  I was considering a re-install so I booted to the install media and selected Recover Windows instead of Install.  From there I was given a menu with several options including Restore System. It allowed me to recover to a previous System Restore point.